# Chrome Canary not detecting available plugins

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-canary

I am using Chrome Canary on Mac OS X Yosemite. I am trying to install the VLC Web Plugin, with the contents of the plugin in `/Users/hanxue/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/VLC Plugin.plugin`. Other than `VLC`, I also have these other plugins:

```
$ ls -1 /Users/hanxue/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
BlueStacks Install Detector.plugin
CitrixOnlineWebDeploymentPlugin.plugin
LWAPlugin15.8.bundle
Picasa.plugin
VLC Plugin.plugin
WebEx64.plugin

$ ls -1 /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
Default Browser.plugin
Disabled Plug-Ins
Flash Player.plugin
Flip4Mac WMV Plugin.plugin
Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin
JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
Mathematica.plugin
MeetingJoinPlugin.plugin
Quartz Composer.webplugin
QvodBrowserPlugin.plugin
QvodPlayerPlugin.plugin
Silverlight.plugin
flashplayer.xpt
googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin
nplastpass.plugin
o1dbrowserplugin.plugin
```

Chrome Canary does not show any of the plug ins:

[image: Plugins in Chrome Canary]

But in `Chromium`, all of those plugins are loaded

[image: Chromium plugins]

How can I get Chrome Canary to load those plugins?